# Selenium error when interacting with textarea

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I try to enter text into text area on the web i am using selenium to do this but when i try to input into textarea it fails with error:"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable".
However when i try to put text into  field it works normaly

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@class = "Ypffh"]').send_keys(text);
```

Comment: Probably it is disabled or something and gets enabled only if you click on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it with javascript:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("textarea.Ypffh").innerText = "xxx"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might need to click on the textarea before you can interact with it.

I would try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@class = "Ypffh"]').click();
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@class = "Ypffh"]').send_keys(text);
```

If that doesn't work, I would check to see if there's a hidden  tag near the textarea that may function as the input receiver rather than the textarea itself. Sometimes you see cases where a textarea is just a visual representation, but doesn't actually receive text, so there may be a hidden  that receives text instead.

Comment: @JustGekto In order to troubleshoot this more, it would be helpful to see more of the HTML on the page. It doesn't have to be the whole page source, but the <textarea> and its surrounding elements would help.

Answer (score 0):

The text box may be located inside of an Iframe which must be navigated to first. Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744219/how-to-enter-text-in-an-iframe-with-selenium-and-python)