# How to enter text in an iframe with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with Python to automate logging in to Autodesk GBS.  I've been able to access the "Sign In" frame like this:

```
driver.get("https://gbs.autodesk.com/GBS/")
btn = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In')
btn.click()
```

I can't seem to access the username text entry element that pops up then.  I think that it's within an iframe, but according to the number of "NoSuchElementException" occurrences I've gotten, none of the 3 iframes that are apparently on the page seem to hold an element with id "userName".

The HTML code for the text field I'm trying to access is here:

```
<input id="userName" name="UserName" autocomplete="off" aria-label="Email text field" tabindex="1" placeholder="name@example.com" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter an email" data-val-length-max="200" class="form-control  customInput2 populated valid">
```

The HTML code for the surrounding iframe (I think) is here:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" scrolling="no" src="/GBS/Authentication/Authenticate?redirectUrl=%2FGBS%2FProject&amp;requestMode=Setup&amp;isIframe=True" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none; width: 345px; height: 513px;">
...
</iframe>
```

I'm very new to both Selenium and Python and after two days of trying to figure this out, I'm totally lost. Any help would be *very* appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to suggestions from arunkvelu and arundeep chohan below, I've made a few changes to my code (posted completely below).  However it's still not able to find the username field (see the error below).  Suggestions?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait as wait

PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://gbs.autodesk.com/GBS/")
btn = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In')
btn.click()

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='oxygen-container']/iframe")))

username_field = driver.find_element_by_id("userName")
username_field.send_keys("test@mail.com")

driver.find_element_by_id("verify_user_btn").click()

password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("mypassword")
```

> File "...", line 17, in  username_field = driver.find_element_by_id("userName")
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="userName"]"}
> (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.183)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" scrolling="no" src="/GBS/Authentication/Authenticate?redirectUrl=%2FGBS%2FProject&amp;requestMode=Setup&amp;isIframe=True" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none; width: 345px; height: 513px;"></iframe>
```

You can do the following to swap to it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='oxygen-container']/iframe")))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Here's the full thing

```
driver.get("https://gbs.autodesk.com/GBS/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign In"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='oxygen-container']/iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userName"))).send_keys("test@mail.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "verify_user_btn"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys("mypassword")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnSubmit"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks!  The wait code and the imports were helpful, but I'm still getting a NoSuchElementException.  I've updated my code above.  Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The iframe tag specifies an inline frame; It is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

Before acting on elements inside iframes, we have to switch to it using

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe reference)
```

In this case, iframe is

```
<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" scrolling="no" src="/GBS/Authentication/Authenticate?redirectUrl=%2FGBS%2FProject&amp;requestMode=Setup&amp;isIframe=True" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none; width: 345px; height: 513px;"></iframe>
```

So we have to find the reference of the iframe and use the reference to switch to the iframe.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='oxygen-container']/iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Note: The iframe reference parameter can be any locator mechanism which can find the iframe. And then enter username and password.

```
username_field = driver.find_element_by_id("userName")
username_field.send_keys("test@mail.com")

driver.find_element_by_id("verify_user_btn").click()

password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("mypassword")
```

Once completed all interactions with the elements of interest inside iframe, switch back to default content. In other words, come out of the iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

You may have to add appropriate waits to allow elements, including iframe, to load.

Comment: Thank you this was super helpful to clarify what I need to do.  Unfortunately it's still not working.  I've updated my code in my original post.  Any more suggestions?